# Added class not taking effect, custom element

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I'm trying to add a class to a custom element, and the class is getting added (confirmed on inspecting the element), but the styles aren't (again, confirmed upon inspection). What am I doing wrong here?
Here is my template code:

```
<template id="callInNotification">

    <style>

        :host {
            width: 220px;
            height: 85px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 75px;
            left: 15px;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-300px);
            transition: 250ms all;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        :host::before {
            content: "Incoming Call";
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-y: 15px;
            background-image: url(/assets/icons/phone-actions-ring.svg);
            background-position-x: center;
            background-size: 27px;
            height: 85px;
            width: 60px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-end;
            background-color: #2485e1;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 700;
            line-height: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        }

        :host.shown {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }

        :host .shown {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }

    </style>

</template>
```

Here is the custom element code (The string "here" is getting logged to the console):

```
class CallIn extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        // get stuff
        const template:HTMLTemplateElement = document.getElementById('callInNotification');
        const templateContent = template.content;

        const shadowRoot:ShadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback(): void {
        this.classList.add("shown");
        console.log('here');
    }

}

customElements.define('call-in', CallIn);
```

And here is where the code is actually being called:

```
const newEle = document.createElement("call-in");
newEle.classList.add("shown");
```

The weird part is, when I add styles directly to the element like this:
    newEle.style.opacity = "1";
    newEle.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";

The styles take affect.

What am I doing wrong here, that my custom element doesn't apply my class's styles?

Answer (score 0):

Well...I will answer my own question. Credit to this article:

https://alligator.io/web-components/styling-custom-elements/

If you want to add a class to your :host, you need to do it this way:

```
:host(.shown) {
    /*styles*/ 
}
```